# Foreach loop for an Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arraylist

Please, how can foreach loop from the second number in an array.

```
$num = array("20","40","89","300","190","15");
$new = 0;
foreach ($num as $val) {
   $new = $val;
  echo "Value: $new\n";
}
```

Result expected is
Value: 40 Value: 89 Value: 300 Value: 190 Value: 15
What am getting is
Value: 20 Value: 40 Value: 89 Value: 300 Value: 190 Value: 15

Comment: Are you really expecting that result you write in your question? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ignore it by comparing `$val` to the first element of the `$num` array, which in this case is `$num[0]`.

```
$num = array("20","40","89","300","190","15");

foreach ($num as $val) {
  if ($val==$num[0]) continue;
  echo "Value: $val\n";
}
```

Or use a boolean flag:

```
$num = array("20","40","89","300","190","15");
$ignoreFirst=true;
foreach ($num as $val) {
  if ($ignoreFirst) {$ignoreFirst=false;continue;}
  echo "Value: $val\n";
}
```

Comment: FYI: the comparison is weak, could turn out with different results. However `0` is the index and `foreach` does offer it, too. Just introduce it, and your solution is stable (it is correct in the general sense already)

Comment: @hakre; `$val` is already the same type as `$num` from its definition.

Comment: Yes, in this case it won't bite, but there are two ways where it _could_: a) duplicates in the array and b) something that a weak comparison would identify as a duplicate. With that specific array given the answer is correct, here `$val == $num[0]` for that `$num` will only be the first array value: `$index === 0`. Doing the index check is only more portable, perhaps better to read and to maintain. That should not say your answer would be wrong, it's only a comment on it.

Comment: @hakre; good point with the dupes, I'll try to remember it!. I was thinking along the lines of associative arrays where each key is unique.

Comment: yes, well spotted: if the array does not have standard zero-index starting keys (as they can be a map in PHP), my `$index === 0` check is not stable at all. and array_key_first() is particularly well fitting for this skip filter condition.

Answer (score 1):

[array_​shift()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) will "*Shift an element off the beginning of array*"

```
<?php
$num = array("20","40","89","300","190","15");
$new = 0;
array_shift($num);
foreach ($num as $val) {
    $new = $val;
    echo "Value: $new\n";
}
```

will output:

```
Value: 40
Value: 89
Value: 300
Value: 190
Value: 15
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to deal with it, e.g. you could unset the first element in the array and then iterate over it, but you could also apply a function that yields all but the first parameter and pass the array as parameters:

```php
$num = ["20", "40", "89", "300", "190", "15"];
$new = 0;
$dropFirst = static fn ($_, string ...$a) => yield from $a;
foreach ($dropFirst(...$num) as $val) {
    $new = $val;
    echo "Value: $new\n";
}
```

I'd say it depends on the context what the needs are in the moment to `foreach` over `$variable`.

The `$dropFirst` above is a quick, hands-on `Iterator` (in form of the `Generator` subtype) and can be easily replaced with other, more verbose things.

E.g. you can wrap the array in an `ArrayIterator` and then use the `LimitIterator`:

```php
$num = ["20", "40", "89", "300", "190", "15"];
$iterator = new LimitIterator(
    new ArrayIterator($num),
    1
);

$new = 0;
foreach ($iterator as $val) {
    $new = $val;
    echo "Value: $new\n";
}
```

This is certainly more lines of code, but you can separate limiting the iteration from the point where it's done (the `foreach`), still passing only a variable around (also known as *inversion of control*).

---

In the opposite you can put the control as well into the `foreach` body and just skip the first element. For example with a simple index check:

```php
$num = ["20", "40", "89", "300", "190", "15"];

$new = 0;
foreach ($num as $index => $val) {
    if (0 === $index) {
        continue;
    }
    $new = $val;
    echo "Value: $new\n";
}
```

---

So even all of these examples are working - as well as the ones in the other answers - you still have to think about where in your case you want to place control:

1. change the original data (redefine)
2. change what is `foreach`'ed over (represent)
3. change the `foreach` body (present)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution (using a loop, and start at 1 instead of 0 for the index):

```
<?php
$num = array("20","40","89","300","190","15");

$index=1;
while ($index < count($num)) {
  echo " Value:". $num[$index] ;
  $index++;
}

?>
```

So if you want to start from the **third** number in an array, change to `$index=2` in the 2nd line.